# Session value from url not passed in another page

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am using get method to display data on page and trying to create session with this get value.

When used print_r($_SESSION) on same page, session name with its value is diplayed...but that session is **not getting passed on another page**.

E.g.

1) User opens link from his email.

2) Url opened in browser address bar is like http://www.example.com/page1.php?data_id=111&data_name=user+full+name&data_email=abc@example.com where `data_id = 111`

3) I am using following code to get `data_id` from **url in address bar** and comparing it with id in mysql database.

```
$id = $_GET['data_id'];

$userdata = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where reg_id=".$id);
$userdata->execute();

/////WORKING OK..
```

4) Setting

```
$_SESSION['my_user"] = $id;

/////WORKING OK..
```

5) Used

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

on same page showing

```
Array ([my_user] => 111)

/////WORKING OK..
```

6) BUT when opening **other page** on same domain and used `print_r($_SESSION)` are not showing 111. I am getting

```
Array ([my_user] => )

//PROBLEM IS HERE...On OTHER PAGE FROM SAME DOMAIN
```

I HAVE TRIED Following Code too...

```
$_SESSION["my_user"] = $id;
$_SESSION["my_user_test"] = 12345;
```

Output on other page is as follows

```
Array ([my_user] => [my_user_test] => 12345)
```

Comment: did you used session_start() on the other page.?

Comment: @RakeshSingh Yes, I have already added if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();  on other page

Comment: Have you session_start() early on both pages?

Comment: @Progrock Yes, I have already added session_start(); on each page

Comment: Try: $_SESSION['my_user"] = 23; on first page, then check on the other.  It looks as if you are assigning null to $_SESSION['my_user'] are you sure $id contains a value?